# Recursive function to call itself untill it returns a value

Tags: php

I am trying to check if a string contains something between `{}` and if it does replace it with what it relates too the issue I am having with this is calling it to itself

For reference lets assume we have a string `https://technologyforthefuture.org/open-doors-challenge/?modalActive=true&video_id={user_video_id}&key-={user_affiliate_id}`

We pass this string into the below function `ParseShortcodes()`

What will happen currently is `{user_video_id}` will be noticed and replaced and then that will be the end of the loop and nothing will be returned because the code is waiting for `$short` to be empty to return template

I had though about calling `ParseShortcodes()` within itself but I dont think this is the right way to do this there must be some better way

```php
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
            $string = ' ' . $string;
            $ini = strpos($string, $start);
            if ($ini == 0) return '';
            $ini += strlen($start);
            $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
            return substr($string, $ini, $len);
        }

        function ParseShortcodes($template,$post_id){
            $short = get_string_between($template,"{","}");

            if($short == "user_affiliate_id"){
                global $wpdb;

                $query = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM wp_uap_affiliates WHERE uid=3");

                $short = $query->id;

                $template = str_replace("{user_affiliate_id}",$short,$template);
            }else if($short == "user_video_id"){
                $template = str_replace("{user_video_id}",$post_id,$template);
            }else if(empty($short)){
                return $template;
            }
        }
```

Comment: This doesn't require recursion. [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) in place of that get_string_between would suffice.

Comment: Can you provide and example of what that would look like with an explanation @mario

Comment: Build on the suggestion of using `str_replace` in your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55105487/replace-substring-with-new-string-php). You may pass an array of things to be replaced and what they should be replaced with and make all of your changes with a single call to `str_replace`.

Comment: My issue comes from the fact that `get_string_between` only gets the first pair it comes across and I dont wanna hardcode a certain order that the shortcodes have to be applied in in case the order changes in the future @Dave

Comment: The arrays aren't/wouldn't be order specific. And it will handle multiple instances of the data too so no recursion is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) to look up **all** `{words}` and pass it to your callback:

```
 $templ = preg_replace_callback("/\{(\w+)\}/", "DoShortCodes", $templ);
```

That will invoke the function, passing only `user_video_id` (or whatever), and replacing it in the source string with its substitute. Thus the callback can be trimmed down to:

```
 function DoShortCodes($m) {
     switch($m[0]) {
         case "vidid": return "0";
         case "userthing": return db("SELECT ? as id", $x)->id;
         default: trigger_error("NO FINDY SHORTCODE");
     }
 }
```

Which obsoletes the replacement step.